# Detecting HeartBeat Using WebCam?

Tags: image-processing, processing, javacv, heartbeat

I am trying to create an application which can detect heartbeat using your computer webcam. I am working on the code since 2 weeks and developed this code and here I got so far

How does it works? Illustrated below ...

1. Detecting face using opencv
2. Getting image of forehead
3. Applying filter to convert it into grayscale image [you can skip it]
4. Finding the average intensity of green pixle per frame
5. Saving the averages into an Array
6. Applying FFT (I have used minim library)Extract heart beat from FFT spectrum (Here, I need some help)

Here, I need help for extracting heartbeat from FFT spectrum. Can anyone help me. [Here](https://github.com/thearn/webcam-pulse-detector), is the similar application developed in python but I am not able to undersand this code so I am developing same in the proessing. Can anyone help me to undersatnd the part of this python code where it is extracting the heartbeat.

```
//---------import required ilbrary -----------
import gab.opencv.*;
import processing.video.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
import ddf.minim.*;
//----------create objects---------------------------------
Capture video; // camera object
OpenCV opencv; // opencv object
Minim       minim;
FFT         fft;
//IIRFilter filt;
//--------- Create ArrayList--------------------------------
ArrayList<Float> poop = new ArrayList(); 
float[] sample;
int bufferSize = 128;
int sampleRate = 512;
int bandWidth = 20;
int centerFreq = 80;
//---------------------------------------------------
void setup() {
  size(640, 480); // size of the window
  minim = new Minim(this);
  fft = new FFT( bufferSize, sampleRate);
  video = new Capture(this, 640/2, 480/2); // initializing video object
  opencv = new OpenCV(this, 640/2, 480/2); // initializing opencv object
  opencv.loadCascade(OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE);  // loading haar cscade file for face detection
  video.start(); // start video
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  // image(video, 0, 0 ); // show video in the background
  opencv.loadImage(video);
  Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect();
  video.loadPixels();
  //------------ Finding faces in the video ----------- 
  float gavg = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
    noFill();
    stroke(#FFB700); // yellow rectangle
    rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height); // creating rectangle around the face (YELLOW)
    stroke(#0070FF); //blue rectangle
    rect(faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height-2*faces[i].height/3); // creating a blue rectangle around the forehead
    //-------------------- storing forehead white rectangle part into an image -------------------
    stroke(0, 255, 255);
    rect(faces[i].x+faces[i].width/2-15, faces[i].y+15, 30, 15);
    PImage img = video.get(faces[i].x+faces[i].width/2-15, faces[i].y+15, 30, 15); // storing the forehead aera into a image
    img.loadPixels();
    img.filter(GRAY); // converting capture image rgb to gray
    img.updatePixels();

    int numPixels = img.width*img.height;
    for (int px = 0; px < numPixels; px++) { // For each pixel in the video frame...
      final color c = img.pixels[px];
      final color luminG = c>>010 & 0xFF;
      final float luminRangeG = luminG/255.0;
      gavg = gavg + luminRangeG;
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    gavg = gavg/numPixels;
    if (poop.size()< bufferSize) {
      poop.add(gavg);
    }
    else poop.remove(0);
  }
  sample = new float[poop.size()];
  for (int i=0;i<poop.size();i++) {
    Float f = (float) poop.get(i);
    sample[i] = f;
  }

  if (sample.length>=bufferSize) {
    //fft.window(FFT.NONE); 
    fft.forward(sample, 0);
    //    bpf = new BandPass(centerFreq, bandwidth, sampleRate);
    //    in.addEffect(bpf);
    float bw = fft.getBandWidth(); // returns the width of each frequency band in the spectrum (in Hz).
    println(bw); // returns 21.5332031 Hz for spectrum [0] & [512]

    for (int i = 0; i < fft.specSize(); i++)
    {
      // println( " Freq" + max(sample));
      stroke(0, 255, 0);
      float x = map(i, 0, fft.specSize(), 0, width);
      line( x, height, x, height - fft.getBand(i)*100);
     // text("FFT FREQ " + fft.getFreq(i), width/2-100, 10*(i+1));
     // text("FFT BAND " + fft.getBand(i), width/2+100, 10*(i+1));
    }
  }
  else {
    println(sample.length + " " + poop.size());
  }
}

void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  c.read();
}
```

Comment: That guys pulse is too high for someone just sitting there...

Comment: @depends on how naked/nasty babe is he looking at ...

Answer (score 3):

The FFT is applied in a window with 128 samples.

```
int bufferSize = 128;
```

During the draw method the samples are stored in a array until fill the buffer for the FFT to be applied. Then after that the buffer is keep full. To insert a new sample the oldest is removed. gavg is the average gray channel color.

```
gavg = gavg/numPixels;
if (poop.size()< bufferSize) {
  poop.add(gavg);
}
else poop.remove(0);
```

Coping poop to sample

```
sample = new float[poop.size()];
for (int i=0;i < poop.size();i++) {
    Float f = (float) poop.get(i);
    sample[i] = f;
}
```

Now is possible to apply the FFT to sample Array

```
fft.forward(sample, 0);
```

In the code is only show the spectrum result. The heartbeat frequency must be calculated.
For each band in fft you have to find the maximum and that position is the frequency of heartbeat.

```
for(int i = 0; i < fft.specSize(); i++)
{ // draw the line for frequency band i, scaling it up a bit so we can see it
    heartBeatFrequency = max(heartBeatFrequency,fft.getBand(i));
}
```

Then get the bandwidth to know the frequency.

```
float bw = fft.getBandWidth();
```

Adjusting frequency.

```
heartBeatFrequency = fft.getBandWidth() * heartBeatFrequency ;
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the kind reply and elaborating my code. I have added your suggested piece of code that you have mentioned in the end of your post. When I run the code it gives me "Infinity" can you please tell me why this is happening? Thanks again :)

Comment: Did you solve?
fft.getBandWidth(), heartBeatFrequency one of those are with infinite value. verify if the heartBeatFrequency is initialized with -infinity and if the fft.getBandWidth() returns a valid value, different of infinity.

Answer (score 0):

After you get samples size 128 that is bufferSize value or greater than that, forward the fft with the samples array and then get the peak value of the spectrum which would be our heartBeatRate
Following Papers explains the same :

1. Measuring Heart Rate from Video - *Isabel Bush* - Stanford - [link](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs231a/prev_projects_2016/finalReport.pdf) (Page 4 paragraphs below Figure 2 explain this.)
2. Real Time Heart Rate Monitoring From Facial RGB Color Video Using Webcam - *H. Rahman, M.U. Ahmed, S. Begum, P. Funk* - [link](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/129/002/ecp16129002.pdf) (Page 4)

---

After looking at your question , I thought let me get my hands onto this and I tried making a [repository](https://github.com/pishangujeniya/FaceToHeart) for this.

Well, having some issues if someone can have a look at it.

Thank you [David Clifte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/940802/david-clifte) for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27317153/7703497) answer it helped a lot.

Comment: Self Promotion Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See:  [What signifies “Good” self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Comment: @Shree Thank you so much for giving me correct guidelines for answers on StackOverFlow.
As I am new into this contribution I would try my best not to break any guidelines.

My intention was not to promote my repository or library or tutorial. I was just willing to notify something that can help others in understanding the same thing in better code manner.

Still thank You much.

Confused should I delete the answer or not ?

Comment: Don't delete but elaborate  how your library solve question.

Comment: @Shree Updated the answer with more information with correct sources.
Thank You so much

Comment: I retract my flag. Now your answer is survive.

Comment: @Shree I realised now what is called happiness.